# "with" function behaviour

Tags: r

Can anyone explain what causes the error in the last line of the code? Is it a bug?

```
> ll <- list(a=1, b=2)
> ee <- as.environment(ll)
> ee
<environment: 0x0000000004d35810>
> ls(ee)
[1] "a" "b"
> with(ee, a)
[1] 1
> with(ee, a - b)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "-"
>
```

Comment: Note that proto objects are environments that work the way you are asking for: `library(proto); p <- proto(a = 1, b = 2); with(p, a - b)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to R's scoping. It needs to find the function `"-"()`. You told R to evaluate your expression in the environment `ee`. There is no function `"-"()` there, so proceeded to the parent environment of `ee`, which is:

```
> parent.env(ee)
<environment: R_EmptyEnv>
```

where there is no function `"-"()` either. As there is no parent environment to the empty environment

```
> parent.env(parent.env(ee))
Error in parent.env(parent.env(ee)) : the empty environment has no parent
```

R gave up the search and threw an error.

We can solve the problem by attaching a parent environment to `ee` where R can find the function:

```
> parent.env(ee) <- .BaseNamespaceEnv
> with(ee, a - b)
[1] -1
```

But I think this would be more natural, to set the parent of `ee` to be the global environment:

```
> parent.env(ee) <- globalenv()
> with(ee, a - b)
[1] -1
```

`a` and `b` will always be found in `ee` as that is the first scoping environment encountered, but the functions can be looked up in the usual place, as if running this at the command line. If you are doing this in a function call, then you'll need to assign the correct environment.

Comment: +1 The source of `with.default` illustrates why the parent environment is important.  And `?as.environment` says if `x` is a list, "the equivalent of `list2env(x, parent=emptyenv())` is returned."  So you could use `list2env` instead of `as.environment` in this case and set the parent environment there.

Comment: Slightly better to use `globalenv()` rather than `.GlobalEnv`

Comment: @hadley thanks for that - missed it in the help page. I've edited the Answer accordingly.

Comment: Given OPs example, why muck around with environments at all?  

You can just use the list directly, e.g. `with(ll, a-b)` and it will work just fine.  

Maybe this is a feature introduced since this question was posted in '11.

Comment: @ChrisWarth It may well be, but as to *why* we're mucking with the environment, your suggestion doesn't account for the fact that the OP is using an environment. I.e. we took the issue to involve explicitly the OP needing to do this on an environment.

Answer (score 5):

The `-` function isn't visible from the environment that you created.

If you assign it there,

```
ee$`-` <- `-`
```

then your example will work.

Comment: So is selling a mortgage around, but that's not stopping anyone. :P